# add_submenu_page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, class, plugins, callback

When using the `add_submenu_page` to create a new submenu in WooCommerce, I get "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent". The `add_submenu_page` is as follows:

```
    public function slp_add_menu_item() {
        add_submenu_page(
            'woocommerce',
            'Shipping Locations',
            'Shipping Locations',
            'manage_options',
            'slp_add_states',
            array( $this->slp_settings_page() ),
        );
    }
```

[image: No errors on callback function]

Changing that to the following removes the "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" errors but fails to render callback function properly:

```
    public function slp_add_menu_item() {
        add_submenu_page(
            'woocommerce',
            'Shipping Locations',
            'Shipping Locations',
            'manage_options',
            'slp_add_states',
            array( $this, 'slp_settings_page' ),
        );
    }
```

[image: Callback function works but table is shown.]

The `slp_settings_page` callback function, in turn, renders an instance of `WP_List_Table` (It's not a taxonomy despite the appearances in the screenshots above). The `add_submenu_page` is added through the `admin_menu` hook without any priorities.

Any ideas on what's happening here? I can't seem to wrap my head around it :(

Comment: Have you tried looking at the line of code where PHP says your output is starting? Can you post that file?

Comment: @DaanMeijer - Absolutely! The four files in the order in which they're being loaded, can be found at: [here](https://pastebin.com/4tSZrWwZ), [here](https://pastebin.com/ULyj3TV0), [here](https://pastebin.com/LRbMExFH) and [here](https://pastebin.com/s17gRJP8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first code block is wrong. According to the documentation the last parameter should be a callable. The first block directly executes the function and stores the result in an array (with the result being `null`, by the way). So, passing that as a callable won't work.

Why the second block isn't working exactly I don't know. Perhaps the code block gets executed at the wrong time, perhaps something else is amiss.